# does SYMENGINE have any effect on integration speed in sympy?

Tags: sympy, symengine

Using sympy 1.10.1 and latest symengine (all installed on Linux Manjaro using the package manager choosing latest versions), I noticed no difference in timing when using symegine vs. not.

Am I using it correctly? Or does symengine have no effect on symbolic integration at this time?

```
unset USE_SYMENGINE
>python
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jun  6 2022, 18:49:26) [GCC 12.1.0] on linux
from sympy import *
import timeit
x,k,a,b,n=symbols('x k a b n')
starttime=timeit.default_timer(); integrate(x**(-1+k)*(a+b*x**k)**n,x); timeit.default_timer()-starttime
Piecewise((log(x)/a, Eq(b, 0) & Eq(k, 0) & Eq(n, -1)), (a**n*x**k/k, Eq(b, 0)), ((a + b)**n*log(x), Eq(k, 0)), (log(a/b + x**k)/(b*k), Eq(n, -1)), (a*(a + b*x**k)**n/(b*k*n + b*k) + b*x**k*(a + b*x**k)**n/(b*k*n + b*k), True))

22.980282188999922
exit()
```

Now try again but set the environment variable to use symengine

```
>export USE_SYMENGINE=1
>python
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jun  6 2022, 18:49:26) [GCC 12.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x,k,a,b,n=symbols('x k a b n')
>>> import timeit
>>> starttime=timeit.default_timer(); integrate(x**(-1+k)*(a+b*x**k)**n,x); timeit.default_timer()-starttime
Piecewise((log(x)/a, Eq(b, 0) & Eq(k, 0) & Eq(n, -1)), (a**n*x**k/k, Eq(b, 0)), ((a + b)**n*log(x), Eq(k, 0)), (log(a/b + x**k)/(b*k), Eq(n, -1)), (a*(a + b*x**k)**n/(b*k*n + b*k) + b*x**k*(a + b*x**k)**n/(b*k*n + b*k), True))
22.583236744000033
>>>
```

Comment: SymEngine has no effect on integration time. Installing gmpy2 can make integration faster in some cases though.

Comment: Selecting different integration algorithms can make a big difference. In this particular case it is heurisch that is slow so you can pass `heurisch=False` or `manual=True` etc.